# pass LD_LIBRARY_PATH to wsgi

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I'm deploying a flask site on a hosting which has two versions of libpq.so. First one is installed in /usr/lib which is used by localy installed psycopg2 library by default:
    ldd _psycopg.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff63b4f000)
    libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib/libpq.so.5 (0x00007fde5d775000)

unfortunatelly this version has no lo_truncate64 symbol:
    python run.app
    undefined symbol: lo_truncate64

but when i'm starting site using localy installed correct version of libpq.so it's stats okay:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/b/.local/lib

i have no administrative rights and can't restart or reconfigure apache 
how can i pass LD_LIBRARY_PATH to wsgi script? SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/b/.local/lib is not working